# How to replace only some Guids from a table to another, under conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a View, but I wanted to change some of the result's Guids to Guids from another table, I want it directly in my view Result and I Don't know how?

```
select  p.[Guid], c.[Guid] detailsGuid
INTO #temp1
from 
ret_PayrollCalculationCommands s INNER JOIN
ret_PayrollCalculations p  ON p.CalculationCommandGuid = s.Guid INNER JOIN
ret_vwPayrollCalculationDetails c ON c.CalculationGuid = p.Guid
```

Comment: Please include some sample data from both tables to make your question concrete.

Comment: here's my Code I want to replace some of p.[Guid]  with s.[Guid]

Comment: Quantify what the word `some` means here.

Comment: sorry, you were right, I've Edited my Question, I mean those p.MainCalculation = 1

Comment: all my tables have one to one relation to eachother

Comment: Try a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should INNER JOIN your table with same table that has target Guid column with another condition:

```
SELECT 
    p.[Guid], 
    c.[Guid] detailsGuid,
    pMainCalculation.[Guid] AS [TargetGuid]
INTO #temp1
FROM 
    ret_PayrollCalculationCommands s INNER JOIN
    ret_PayrollCalculations p  ON p.CalculationCommandGuid = s.Guid INNER JOIN 
    ret_PayrollCalculations pMainCalculation ON pMainCalculation.CalculationCommandGuid = p.CalculationCommandGuid AND pMainCalculation.MainCalculation = 1 INNER JOIN
    ret_vwPayrollCalculationDetails c ON c.CalculationGuid = p.Guid
```